# Swagger array of strings without name

Tags: arrays, api, documentation, swagger, swagger-ui

Currently I am trying to create a swagger file for my software.
Now I would like to create a definition for a timeRange.
My problem is that this array looks like this:

```
timeRange: {
  "2016-01-15T09:00:00.000Z", // this is the start date
  "2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z" // this is the end date
}
```

How can I create an example value that works out of the box?
It is an "array of strings" with a minimum of two.

```
"timeRange": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string",
    "example": "2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z,2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z"
  }
}
```

This generates an example like this:

```
"timeRange": [
  "2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z,2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z"
]
```

This example does not work, because it is an array and not an object.
All together:
How can I realize an example value that exists out of two different strings (without a name).

Hope you can help me!
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
timeRange: {
  "2016-01-15T09:00:00.000Z", // this is the start date
  "2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z" // this is the end date
}
```

is not valid JSON – `"timeRange"` needs to be enclosed in quotes, and the object/array syntax should be different.

If using the object syntax `{}`, the values need to be named properties:

```
"timeRange": {
  "start_date": "2016-01-15T09:00:00.000Z",
  "end_date": "2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z"
}
```

Otherwise `timeRange` needs to be an `[]` array:

```
"timeRange": [
  "2016-01-15T09:00:00.000Z",
  "2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z"
]
```

In the first example (`{}` object), your Swagger would look as follows, with a separate `example` for each named property:

```
"timeRange": {
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "start_date": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time",
      "example": "2016-01-15T09:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "end_date": {
      "type": "string",
      "format": "date-time",
      "example": "2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z"
    }
  },
  "required": ["start_date", "end_date"]
}
```

In case of an `[]` array, you can specify an array-level `example` that is a multi-item array:

```
"timeRange": {
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
    "type": "string",
    "format": "date-time"
  },
  "example": [
    "2016-01-15T09:00:00.000Z",
    "2017-01-15T09:00:00.000Z"
  ]
}
```

Comment: thank you very much.
This is exactly what I was looking for.
I have been looking through the swagger documentation but could not find anything like this!